# How to check if a class instance has been created or is null C#

Tags: c#, class

How do you check if `classinstance` has been created/initialised or is `null`?

```
private MyClass myclass;

if(!check class has been initialised)      //<- What would that check be?
    myclass = new MyClass();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I note that you've tagged this question as involving ASP.Net. Is there some additional trickiness to this question because of that fact?

Comment: is this homework ? if so please retag it as such

Comment: @MicahArmantrout No, I just used `myclass.Equals(null)` which threw an exception, but I didn't try the simple `==`.

Comment: Normally one would do `==`. Another possibility is `Equals(myclass, null)`. Note that it's the static version of `Equals` which has two arguments. There's also `ReferenceEquals`. If you haven't done anything to change the meaning of `==` or of `Equals`, then for `MyClass`, all these three are equivalent (for a `class` type).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just check if it is null

```
if (myclass == null)
```

As mentioned in your comment,

```
if (myclass.Equals(null))
```

will not work because if myclass is null, that's translated to

```
if (null.Equals(null))
```

which leads to a `NullReferenceException`.

By the way, objects declared in class scope are automatically initialized to null by the compiler, so your line:

```
private MyClass myclass;
```

is the same as

```
private MyClass myclass = null;
```

Objects declared in a method are forced to be assigned some initial value (even if that initial value is null).

Comment: Yeah that works, thanks. I used `myclass.Equals(null)` which didn't work.

Comment: Correct.  It did not work because myclass was null, and null.Equals(null) should give a NullReferenceException :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (myclass == null)
    myclass = new MyClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to restrict a class to a single instance, have a look at the Singleton design pattern: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can use this constructions for avoid checking

```
    public class SomeClass
    {
        private MyClass _myClass;
        public MyClass MyClass
        {
            get { return _myClass ?? (_myClass = new MyClass()); }
            set { _myClass = value; }
        }
    }

    public class SomeClass
    {
        private readonly MyClass _myClass = new MyClass();
        public MyClass MyClass
        {
            get { return _myClass; }
        }
    }
```